# usb devices android, c# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, usb, xamarin.android, xamarin

I recently started writing on Xamarin, and I've got some problems with writing code to look at the devices attached to my host.

I've read the SDK documentations, and all the docs are written in java. I'm trying to change java into C#, and I coded this to find the devices attached:

```
UsbManager manager = (UsbManager)GetSystemService (Context.UsbService);
display.Text += " /n inizializzo il manager";
display.Text += "numero dispositivi: ";
display.Text += manager.DeviceList.Count;
```

With "usb manager" app I can see all the usb attached, there are 3. But with this code it appears to be 0 usb attached.

I don't understand why.

Comment: Dammit.. I was stuck on this problem. I couldn't even use Android.Hardware.Usb thus anything else USB related. It turns out I was working on a project for Android 2.2 and USB host isn't supported on that version. Fixing my problem 5 min after I opened the bounty :D

Answer (score 3):

Well it looks like you've already solved this one, I may have some additional tips for you though. First of all like you've found out USB-host is only supported in Android 3.1 and higher versions. Second of all, you need to add the "uses-feature " to the  android manifest.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="false" />
```

Be sure to include required="false" to make sure that your app can be installed and started on device that do not support USB-host (if usb-host is optional for your app).

Third you'd  be surprised how many modern mobile devices do not support host mode yet and fourth, the USB-port needs to supply enough power for the attached usb-device. Fifth and last point: Android is not really suited for high-speed "real-time" usb-communications. Android has a nasty habit of pausing the whole system and collecting garbage before "unblocking" and moving on. If you're trying to send a lot of data via usb at a constant rate this can cause the buffer to fill up when Android pauses and GC's, and at the next read to the buffer you may find corrupted data. So be sure to watch your memory management when building an app that includes usb-communications! I've found that configuring the Xamarin GC bridge to "Tarjan" mode helps quite a bit in reducing GC-induced pauses, this  might be specific to  my app though.

Maybe not a great fit as an answer to your question, but I was feeling chatty ;). Good luck!

- Edit: Did not notice that OP didn't specify whether he wants to use a usb accessory or a usb-host device. For an accessory, use Mike Stonis' tip!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you do not have the proper settings in your manifest. Review the provided settings at the [Android USB Accessory Help page](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/accessory.html#manifest).

At a minimum, you will need to add the following line to your AndroidManifest.xml file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
```

***Hint:** The AndroidManifest.xml is located under the Properties section in a Xamarin project.*